# Expecting StringLiteral near 'inpath' in load statement

Tags: scala, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I'm very new to hadoop and hive. 
I'm trying to load data into a hive table and I'm experiencing the error below.

On the other hand I tried to insert the record into hive table using the statement `stmt.execute("INSERT INTO employee VALUES(1201,'Gopal',45000,'Technical manager')")`
it is inserting the record successfully, but while loading bulk of data it fails.

```
val filePath=C:\\AllProjects\\xxxxxxx\\src\\main\\resources\\input\\sample.txt
val con = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://xxxxxhive.xxxx.com:10000/dehl_dop;principal=hive/xxxxxhive.com.com@internal.xxxxx.com;" +
"mapred.job.queue.name=usa;AuthMech=3;SSL=1;user=zzzz;password=vvvv;" +
"SSLTrustStore=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_144\\lib\\security\\hjsecacerts;UseNativeQuery=0")
val stmt = con.createStatement()
print("\n" + "executing the query" +"\n")
stmt.execute(s"load data inpath $filePath into table Employee")
```

Error

```
errorMessage:Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:17 mismatched input 'C' expecting StringLiteral near 'inpath' in load statement), Query: load data inpath C:\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\sample.txt into table Employee.
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `val filePath` is a String? If so, it needs quotes...

Comment: yes, it is string.

Answer (score 1):

`LOAD DATA INPATH` takes a string literal.

`$filePath` needs single quotes around it

```
stmt.execute(s"load data inpath '$filePath' into table Employee")
```

However, that command requires a file **be located on HDFS**. And you're reading from your C drive

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH` will read the **local** filesystem, but I'm not sure how that works over JDBC because it depends on where the query is actually executed (your local machine, or the HiveServer)

I suggest you create an external Hive table at a specific HDFS location, with the necessary schema, then simply copy the text file directly to HDFS.

Programmatically copying the file to HDFS is an option, but `hadoop fs -put` would be simpler.

If all you want to do is load a local file to HDFS/Hive, Spark would make more sense than JDBC

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Sample App").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.option("header", "false").csv(filePath)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("emp")
spark.sql("INSERT INTO dehl_dop.Employee SELECT * from emp")
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,still issue is persist. Basically I'm trying to load file(It is normal txt file located in my somewhere in C drive,not a hdfs file) from my local system to hive table(hive table is in Cloudera server).

Comment: Hive is not specific to Cloudera, but I highly doubt that will work the way you want using JDBC. I suggest you just use Spark

Comment: You could also use Hue to 1) upload the file to HDFS 2) create the table graphically http://gethue.com/import-data-to-be-queried-via-the-self-service-drag-drop-create-table-wizard/